# How do I change my Admin theme?

Tags: theming

I'm brand new to Drupal and have just installed Drupal 7. When I was configuring it, I originally selected "Stark" as my Admin theme, thinking I would create my own CSS later. In trying to learn Drupal and add content, I have decided that I would like to change my Admin theme. I went to the Admin tool bar (across the top) and clicked "Appearance" and changed my theme there, I even disabled the "Stark" theme, but my Admin theme is still defaulting to the Stark theme. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `admin/appearance` and you will see a fieldgroup called "Administration theme" at the bottom.

Comment: I did that already - it does not work! I have my Admin theme at the very bottom set to "Garland" and I have the check box selected for "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" and I have saved the configuration (several times!) It is NOT working! What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error
the code not working because i use Bootstrap theme, and administration theme use Seven theme, just change the administration theme to bootstrap or put the code under Seven code